# how to change Text() when changing TextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

how to change Text() when changing TextField
MyComposable:

class Cycle(val title: String)

from ViewModel recived Flow

```
@Composable
    fun MyColumn(){
    Column(){
      val cycleVM : CycleVM  = viewmodel()  
      val cycle by cycleVM.cycle.collectAsState()

    MyText(cycle)
    MyTextField(cycle)
    
    }
```

MyTextField :

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField(cycle: Cycle) {
            var title by remember {
                mutableStateOf(cycle.title!!)
            }

            TextField(modifier = modifierValue.fillMaxWidth(),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = colorResource(R.color.colorBackgroundCardView)
                ),
                value = title,
                onValueChange = {
                    title = it
                    cycle.title = it
                }
               }
            )
}
```

MyText:

@Composable
fun MyTextField(cycle: Cycle) {

```
 Text(
        modifier = modifier1,
        style = MyTextTitleLabel20StrokeText,
        text = if (cycle.title.isBlank()) {
            stringResource(id = R.string.title_cycle_hint)
        } else {
            cycle.title
        }
    )
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `title` property inside the `Cycle` class is not a StateFlow, so Jetpack Compose doesn't know when that property changes and can't "recompose" the text.

Instead of passing the entire class to the composables as a parameter, you should share only the informations needed inside them:

```
@Composable
fun MyColumn(){
    Column(){
        // val cycle  from viemodel

        var title by remember {
            mutableStateOf(cycle.title)
        }

        MyText(title)
        MyTextField(title)
    }
}

@Composable
MyText(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier(),
    title: MutableState<String>
){
    Text(
        modifier = modifier,
        style = MyTextTitleLabel20StrokeText,
        text = if (title.isBlank()) {
            stringResource(id = R.string.title_cycle_hint)
        } else {
            title
        }
    )
}
```

Or, you could make the `title` property a StateFlow inside the `Cycle` class. (But that's an incorrect approach)

Comment: But I get from ModelView my Cycle.    val cycleVM : CycleVM  = viewmodel()     val cycle by cycleVM.cycle.collectAsState()